# query selector value is not getting in jasmine unit testing angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have two input fields like below

```
<input type="number" [value]="celsius" class="large" data-test-id="celsius-input" (keyup)="getCelsius($event)">

<input type="number" [value]="fahren" class="large" (keyup)="getFahren($event)" data-test-id="fahrenheit-input"/>
```

now I'm trying testing this using jasmine unit testing. for this I have written code like below

```
let component: TemperatureConverter;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TemperatureConverter>;
  let compiled;
  let celsiusInput;
  let fahrenheitInput;

  const pushCelsiusValue = async (value) => {
    celsiusInput.value = value;
    celsiusInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    celsiusInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    await fixture.whenStable();
    await fixture.detectChanges();
  };

  const pushFahrenheitValue = async (value) => {
    fahrenheitInput.value = value;
    fahrenheitInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    fahrenheitInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    await fixture.whenStable();
    await fixture.detectChanges();
  }

  const getByTestId = (testId: string) => {
    return compiled.querySelector(`[data-test-id="${testId}"]`);
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TemperatureConverter);
    fixture.autoDetectChanges(true);
    compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    celsiusInput = getByTestId('celsius-input');
    fahrenheitInput = getByTestId('fahrenheit-input');
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('Typing value in Celsius field gets correct Fahrenheit value', async() => {
    await pushCelsiusValue(500);
    fahrenheitInput = getByTestId('fahrenheit-input');
    expect(Number(fahrenheitInput.value)).toEqual(932);
  });
```

but I'm not able to get any value  `fahrenheitInput = getByTestId('fahrenheit-input');` and I'm not to match anything in     `expect(Number(fahrenheitInput.value)).toEqual(932);`

I'm not able to figure out what is the error.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `compiled` is stale after you change the dom, you need to see the current value of the DOM.

I would do:

```
it('Typing value in Celsius field gets correct Fahrenheit value', async() => {
    await pushCelsiusValue(500);
    // we changed the dom with pushCelsiusValue so we need to see how the fixture changed
    // as well. Therefore assign fahrenheightInput to a new reference of fixture.debug.nativeElement
    // and not the old compiled reference
    fahrenheitInput = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('[data-test-id=fahrenheit-input]');
    expect(Number(fahrenheitInput.value)).toEqual(932);
  });
```

Comment: rather than giving a actual input value it is giving `<input _ngcontent-a-c45="" type="number" data-test-id="fahrenheit-input" class="large">
`

Comment: I made a comment. You need to add nativeElement in the 2nd last line.

Comment: I have added but it coming result as `undefined`

Comment: Sorry, that last `nativeElement` is not needed. It is giving HTML without the `nativeElement`, what does `fahrenheightInput.value` give?